# How to find zero with regular expression

Tags: search, python-re

A task:
You have a string that consist only of digits. You need to find how many zero digits ("0") are at the beginning of the given string.

```
result = re.search(r'^["0"]+', str)
```

I use re module, but I get a None

Comment: `result = len(re.search("^0*", str).group(0))`

Comment: Anyway with that code you shouldn't get `None`. Are you sure `str` starts with some `0`?